SQL Server TRIGGER with JOIN
I am trying to write a TRIGGER that when certain conditions are met, the transaction must be rolled back. My script currently is as follows:
CREATE TRIGGER trg_AfterInsert_On_InvNum
ON InvNum
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Action AS CHAR(1);

    SET @Action = (
        CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM INSERTED I
                    JOIN _evInvNumUDFLink UDF ON I.AutoIndex = UDF.AutoIndex
                    WHERE I.DocType = 5 
                        AND I.DocState = 1 
                        AND I.DocVersion = 1 
                        AND UDF.ubIDPOrdPriceChecked = 0)
            THEN 'I'  -- Set Action to Updated.
            ELSE NULL
            END)

    -- Check if the inserted row meets the specified conditions
    BEGIN
        IF @Action = 'I'
            RAISERROR ('Your order has not been placed', 16, 1);    

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END
END;

One of the columns that I need to check, comes from a different table _evInvNumUDFLink which I had to join to the 'INSERTED' table. This is not working, and I'm wondering if it's because of the JOIN?
I still have much more to add to this trigger, but I need to get this part correct first.
Perhaps I could get some guidance here?

I am not sure if it is even possible to rollback a transaction in a trigger, that was started somewhere else. And even if it is possible that looks like a terrible idea to me. You could throw an error (not raiserror which is deprecated) and then in the catch exception of the caller do the rollback

What does "not working" mean?

@GuidoG totally, in fact even without explicitly calling rollback an error in a trigger will rollback the entire transaction it's contained with because it runs with xact_abort on by default.

@DaleK True but I still think it's a bad idea to rollback inside a trigger

You should definitely be using throw not raiserror which I am pretty sure automatically rolls back the transaction

@DaleK - basically this trigger sits on the InvNum table, which is where Purchase Orders are posted. When the conditions are met, I dont want the PO to be posted to the InvNum table. Before I added the JOIN, the trigger worked fine, but after I added it, it blocks all PO from being posted

Test out your query in a test environment. You can create a temp table in place of inserted.

Btw you don't need both exists conditions as if the second is true then so is the first.

Fundamentally if adding the join broke the trigger, then your join conditions must be wrong.

Um, you do realise your code will always rollback? You have your begin before your if when I think you meant it to be after. if without a begin only applies to the single statement following

Triggers are great when you use them with care.
Don't do to much in them because they can pull the performance on that table down and its hard to trace where an error comes from when you are debugging.
You can join as much as you like, that has nothing to do with your problem.
Anyway, doing a rollback from a trigger is not done, who ever does the insert on that table should do so in a try... catch and in the catch handle the error and there do the rollback.
An example of your trigger could be this
create trigger trg_AfterInsert_On_InvNum on InvNum
after insert as
begin
     set nocount on;
     
     if exists (select 1
       from inserted i
       inner join _evInvNumUDFLink UDF on i.AutoIndex = UDF.AutoIndex
       where i.DocType = 5 
       and   i.DocState = 1 
       and   i.DocVersion = 1 
       and   UDF.ubIDPOrdPriceChecked = 0
     )   
     begin
          THROW 51000, N'Your order has not been placed', 1;
     end;
 end;


Doesn't throwing an error automatically rollback the insert?

it should rollback @DaleK

Thanks @GuidoG - I get the following error for this: Incorrect syntax for THROW. Expecting CONVERSATION, DIALOG, DISTRIBUTED or TRANSACTION.

@DaleK If you don't catch the exception and rollback yourself, than the database will rollback for you eventually. In my opinion you should avoid that and do it yourself, but that's just my opinion offcourse

Better to use if exists, selecting out values can mess up callers up the stack that don't expect resultsets

@GrayMeiring what's your sql server version? SELECT @@VERSION

Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64)   Oct  8 2022 05:58:25   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0  (Build 19044: )

If you have some other code before THROW, you must end the code with ;

are you aware, that inserted and deleted are tables and you are processing just one row.

@PowerMouse yes I am aware of that, are you aware that in this case that doesn't matter? If one row exists with the given conditions the throw should be executed.
